# How to run a command on remote host from a service?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, ssh

I have a service in '/etc/init.d'. In that service, I run a command on a remote machine using ssh as a user. Currently I do this in the following way:

```
sudo -u user bash -c "ssh user@172.21.6.70 'source ~/.envrc ; (cd /catalog; ./bin/catalog start &)'"
```

This is the start command of that service and the service name is catalog.

When I do `sudo service catatlog start` the command runs successfully i.e it properly SSH'es into the target machine which is `user@172.21.6.70` as the user `user` but it does not start the service.

Can anyone tell me how to tweak this so that it runs successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it by using `nohup` command:

```
sudo -iu user ssh user@172.21.6.70 "nohup bash -c 'source ~/.envrc ; (cd /catalog; ./bin/catalog start &)'"
```